# HTMLInputHidden Null Termination Character

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTMLInputHidden control into which I am putting a string with a \0. Now I am not expecting this to work as a Null Termination Character, however in IE, when getting the .Value of the HTMLInputHidden control in code, anything after the \0 is gone. In Chrome it is not. When running a window.alert("first\0second"); we also get different results from IE (first part only) to Chrome (full string).

The alert part I can understand as someone explained to me previously, that it uses the underlying browser code and IE might be using C\C++ and therefore it is being terminated, but does the HTMLInputHidden also use the underlying code? If anyone can answer why this happens I'd be very thankful!

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+0000 NUL is forbidden in all versions of HTML. Although HTML5 CR specifies error handling rules for it in HTML parsing, NUL is known to cause problems in browsers. It might be argued that HTML rules do not apply to `\0`, which is just two printable Ascii characters as far as HTML is considered and gets interpreted as NUL by JavaScript interpreters. But using NUL that way in HTML documents violates at least the spirit of HTML and should not be expected to work reliably.

However, it seems that your issue is with the `alert()` method (and possibly other methods) on IE. If you test e.g. with `window.alert("first\0second".length)` and inspect the string, you will see that NUL and the characters after it are stored in the string, but `alert()` stops printing at NUL. You can circumvent this by using your own code that handles a string that may contain NUL characters.

Answer (score 0):

The NULL Character is described here:

[JavaScript RegExp \0 Metacharacter](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_nul.asp)

I.E is behaving as the page above describes.  For Chrome, try:

```
new RegExp("\\0")

or simply:

/\0/
```

As a Second approach, modify the JavaScript to look for a [HTML Special Character](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html).

Comment: My question is why is it showing different results from IE to Chrome? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_nul if after the var str... line you add a new line with window.alert(str) and run that in Chrome and IE you will see what I mean (I hope).

Comment: I did that, IE stops processing when a match is found... in the script editor, 16 characters and stops.  Chrome still finds the character at 16, but displays the entire string.  In short, chrome doesn't stop when a match is found, but knows there's a match